# Complexity analysis with loop unrolling

Tags: algorithm

I want to know if the time taken to complete a program (barring cache effects and anything else) is any different if you unroll the loop once. Essentially, is there any difference in
the 2 loops: `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)` and `for(i = 0; i < n/2; i++)` if you access double the number of elements in the second loop as compared to the first loop? Do both the loops take the same time to finish, or does one finish before another?

Answer (score 2):

Complexity analysis does not take unrolling into consideration: an unrolled loop iterating N times is still O(n).

The only thing the unrolling is good for is reducing the overhead. In a typical loop you have to do three things repeatedly:

1. Check if you are done
2. Execute the "payload" body of the loop
3. Adjust the loop counter

If a loop repeats N times, each of these three steps is repeated N times as well. Note, however, that the first and the last steps are pure overhead: they are there to deal with loop bookkeeping.

When you unroll the loop once, you cut half of steps 1 and 3, while step 2 is repeated N times. The complexity is the same, yet the overhead is only 50% of what it used to be.

Note: One observation that follows from this is that unrolling makes most sense when the timing of your payload activity is comparable with the timing of the overhead. For example, if the payload takes 10ms and the overhead is also 10ms, eliminating 50% of the overhead speeds up the loop by 25%. If the overhead is 1ms and the payload is 10ms, however, unrolling gives you back only 0.5/11, or 4.5%.

Comment: `you cut half of steps 1 and 3` No, you cannot cut in half step 3, there is increment somewhere (though not applied to loop counter) to access second "payload" in one cycle

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux In many cases the second increment can be optimized away quite nicely. For example, when C compiler sees `a[i+1]`, it adds `1` to the address of `a` at compile time, and uses the new offset. The increment is done once, but now the step is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Loop unrolling is a form of optimization, as it reduces the number of increment, compare and jump operations. (Though leave the actual unrolling and other optimizations to the compiler, it will usually find more efficient ways to do it. If you think you know better - prove it!)

Unrolling does not change the complexity class of the problem, though. The complexity of a problem is usually not determined by constant factors, like loop overhead, and really only works out at higher numbers. (For example, `O(n*log(n))` Quicksort or Mergesort are often only used to break down the list to sort into short segments, while `O(n²)` Insertsort is then used to sort those due to the lower overhead.)

Answer (score 0):

If work-per-cycle is comparable to loop overhead, then unrolling might improve performance. From the other hand, you'll have more instructions to execute in one loop cycle. If your instruction cache is small and filled, then your unrolling might make things worse.

Try and measure, that's the only way to prove or disprove guesses

For a fun reading, here is original loop unroller, Duff's device

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/duffs-device.html#duffs-device

On one tight loop it once gave me 4% boost